# combining gnuplot with a gui in haskell

Tags: haskell, visualization, gnuplot

Can any one provide an example , or advice as to what would be the best approach for using gnu-plot or something similar from within a Haskell GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `Chart` package and the [`plot`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plot) package both use `cairo` as a 2D renderer which can be used with GTK.

The `plot-gtk` package provides a custom widget to display plots in GTK.  `plot` can plot functions or data series which are `Data.Vector.Storable` from the `vector` package and thus are compatible with `hmatrix` and friends.

There is an example in the plot package in  [`Graphics.Rendering.Plot`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/plot/0.1.4.1/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-Plot.html)